# How to add a credit card logo at the bottom of all pages of a Shopify site

Tags: frontend, shopify, backend, e-commerce, liquid

Reviewing our Shopify site, I realized that a major difficulty with Shopify is that it's as if the theme does everything possible to obfuscate credit card usage. The site is replete with all sorts of references to Google Pay, Amazon Pay, etc., but credit card payments are always difficult to find.

I would like to know how to add a credit card logo in the bottom of all pages and remove the default logos already there. Could you please let me know if it is possible to do it in Shopify by editing LIQUID file? If so, please point me

[image]

Comment: look for the footer.liquid file in sections folder

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks

Comment: It worked, thanks. I would accept it as answer if you could convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually the page is break into 3 sections (files are stored in section folder). `header.liquid` , `content_for_layout` and `footer.liquid`

you can find the layout in `/layout/theme.liquid`

for your case, the credits icons are all in the `sections/footer.liquid`

Comment: Charles, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked